# Convergence of sum of random numbers

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm not too sure if this is a sensible, well-defined question to ask, but there's no harm in asking, so here goes.

Say I draw a number from the uniform distribution on the unit interval. I draw another number and add it to the first. I draw more numbers and keep adding them. If I continue this for infinitely many steps, how likely is it that this 'random sum' will converge?

That's the basic idea I want to ask. Let me try making it a bit more formal: Let $X_i\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ for all $i$, and let $X_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Then we can define $X_\infty=\lim_{n\to\infty}X_n$. Now, I want to know $P(X_\infty < \infty)$.

If you can share other interesting properties of $X_\infty$, that would be cool too.

Comment: You are using $X_n$ to mean two different things.  I think you want to consider $Y_n=\sum_{i\leq n}X_n$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n$

Comment: Take any positive real number $r<1$. Then, you will pick up a number with at least value $r$ infinite many often with probability $1$. Hence the sum will diverge with probability $1$.

Comment: @saulspatz Ah yes, sorry. Thanks for correcting my sloppiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X_n$ to converge, you need that for any $\epsilon >0$, there is $n_0$ such that if $n > n_0$, $|X_n - X_{n_0}| < \epsilon$. However, this would imply that for every $\epsilon >0$, there is an index, $n_0$, after which, at the very least, every drawn value is smaller than $\epsilon$. However, for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$, and infinitely many draws from the unit interval, the probability of all draws being smaller than $\epsilon$ tends to $0$.

Putting it another way, "almost all" sums formed from numbers in the unit interval do *not* converge.